# Restrict Response Body Size of HTTP POST Method

Tags: http, jmeter, http-headers, load-testing

I am currently setting up a POST HTTP request test case in JMeter. In this case it takes very long until one iteration is threw so the next does start. I suppose that the server spends a lot of time with downloading the response body of the request - which in this case may be quite large:

[image]

So here is my question:

Is there some way to restrict the size of a HTTP response body or something similar?

Thank you & BR!

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is [stateful](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-stateless-and-stateful-protocol/) protocol therefore there is no way to retrieve only partial response so normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler will be receiving the data until the end or the error occurs, whatever comes the first.

I would recommend double-checking your requirement cause it sounds like you want to get false-positive result by retrieving much less content than it will be in the reality.

If this is **really** something you're looking for, you can request an arbitrary range of bytes using [Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range)

1. Add HTTP Header Manager as a child of the request which produces the large response
2. Add `Range` header with the value of `bytes=0-10`

   [image]
3. That's it, the server response will be truncated to the first 10 bytes

   [image]

   as a side-effect you will get [HTTP Status Code 206 - Partial Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but HTTP is stateless by very definition. And even more, there's no connection between statefulness/statelessness per se & ability to have "partial responses" - there's no therefore.